# Unable to create object with Many-to-many relation and request data in multipart/form-data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a user model with many to many relationships with the model team:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
"""
    model to store user infomation
"""
.....
team = models.ManyToManyField(
    "team.Team", blank=True,
    related_name="team_member")
.....
```

Here is a snippet of UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""
    User serializer for user ModelViewSet
"""
.....
team = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
     queryset=Team.objects.all(), many=True,
     required=False,
     allow_null=True,
     )
.....

class Meta:
    model = User
    exclude = ()
```

and here is the view for same:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
""" User model view """
.....

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.data._mutable = True
    team = request.data.get('team')
    team = json.loads(team)
    request.data['team'] = team
    serializer = self.get_serializer_class()
    serializer = serializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        .....
```

Below is attached screenshots of request body using postman form-data:

[image: sample request body]

Anyone can guide me on what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with getlist() method instead of get() method as like:

```
team = request.data.getlist('team[]')
```

Comment: getlist() will still not be helpful as after that I get ['[1,2,3]'] and will have to again access this using index to parse into JSON further.

Comment: Can't you pass your data in JSON format instead of form data?

Comment: No, my model has an ImageField also.

Comment: Then for form data, I think this method only works!

Comment: still I am facing same issue as response is same as previous.

Comment: sorry, can you please try this: request.POST.getlist('team[]')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207593/discussion-between-aayush-bhatnagar-and-meha-parekh).